# MySQL statement combining a join and a count?

Tags: sql, join, count

I've got a table of 'folders'. I want to return all the records with the userId of 16.

```
SELECT * FROM `folders` WHERE userId = 16;
```

I've got a table of 'files'. For each 'folder' returned above, I want to return a count of 'files' within that 'folder'.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as "Files" FROM files WHERE Folder = n;
```

How do I combine these? I'm lost. Thanks!

Answer (score 52, accepted):

```
SELECT  fol.*
 ,      (       SELECT  COUNT(*)
                FROM    files           fil
                WHERE   fil.Folder      = fol.Folder
        )       AS      "Files"
FROM    folders         fol
WHERE   fol.userId      = 16
```

It's called a correlated subquery.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/correlated-subqueries.html

Answer (score 15):

you would probably need to use GROUP BY and group it by ID or such:

```
SELECT 
    folders.*,
    COUNT(files.*) as filetotal 
FROM folders 
    LEFT JOIN files ON folders.ID=files.folderID 
WHERE userId = 16 
GROUP BY folders.ID
```

Comment: This is wrong.  The columns referenced in folders.* have to be in the GROUP BY clause.  All columns in a SELECT statement with a GROUP BY have to either be in a GROUP BY or an aggregate function.

Comment: yeah, that's why i am groupping by folders.ID (one column is enough to group on).

Comment: To get this to work you will need to GROUP BY all of the required columns from "folders" that are mentioned in the SELECT clause - I tested the theory of "one column is enough to group on" and it's not true in SQL Server 2005 at least.

Comment: It's never a good idea to use SELECT * anyway but to specify all of the columns to be returned explicitly.

Comment: he had there * in his original query, i don't know what his table looks like, so stop trolling and use your wits for something creative.

Comment: Sweet syntactic sugar:  <http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html>.  That'll teach me to talk about a product I don't use every day.

Comment: I do believe this is the more classic SQL approach. Nice, and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 4):

Do a sub query that groups by the Folders to get the count per folder, then join it
to the first query like this:

```
    select
       f.*
       fc.Files
    from
       Folders f
--
       -- Join the sub query with the counts by folder     
       JOIN (select
               Folder,
               count(*) Files
             from
                files
             group by
                Folder ) as fc
          on ( fc.Folder = f.Folder )
    where
       f.userid = 16
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select 
    f.`folder`,
    f.`userId`,
    r.`count`

from
    `folders` f
    left join 
    (
        select 
            `Folder`,
            count(`id`) `count`

        from `files`

            group by `Folder`
    ) r
        on r.`Folder`=f.`folder`

where 
    `userId`=16
```

if you do not want to use the group by statement.

i had a simmilar problem in a product list where i wanted to count the star rating of a product in another table [1-5] and the amount of users that voted for that specific product.