# PHP & MySQL query value question

Tags: php, mysql

How can I use the first query's id value `$row['id']` again after I run a second query inside the while loop statement? To show you what I mean here is a sample code below of what I'm trying to do.

I hope I explained it right.

Here is the code.

```
    $mysqli = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "sitename");
    $dbc = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT users.*
                                 FROM users
                                 WHERE user_id = 4");

    if (!$dbc) {
        // There was an error...do something about it here...
        print mysqli_error($mysqli);
    }

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($dbc)) {

     echo '<div>User: ' . $row['id'] . '</div>';
     echo '<div>Link To User' . $row['id'] . '</div>';


            $mysqli = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "sitename");
            $dbc2 = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT COUNT(cid) as num
                                          FROM comments
                                          WHERE comments_id = $row[id]");

            if (!$dbc2) {
                // There was an error...do something about it here...
                print mysqli_error($mysqli);
            }  else {
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($dbc2)){ 
                    $num = $row['num'];
                }
            }

     echo '<div>User ' . $row['id'] . ' Comments# ' . $num . '</div>';

    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you. `$row['id']` will always contain the same value until you assign it something else (each iteration through the loop), no matter how many times you reference it. Could you try to rephrase your question or elaborate?

Comment: but for some reason when I use it in my second query I can't use it again in my first query.

Comment: why are you establishing two database connections? you're not closing any connections either, at least not in this snippet.

Answer (score 3):

Uh.... why don't you just make your second "row" variable something else?  $row2?  I'm a bit confused by your question...

Comment: +1 Ah, now I see it. Yeah this is gotta be what the OP meant, and thus the answer.

Comment: I'm trying to use the first query's id value after the second query runs.

Comment: yes, but the only problem I see here is that you're over-writing the values in the $row array.  Create different variable to store the results of your second query.  If that doesn't do it, then I think we're missing some important parts of the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Every time you see nested query - you know you'rе doing something wrong. No exceptions.

Your query must be like this (I am not sure about column names but hope you have got an idea):

```
$sql = "SELECT users.*, COUNT(cid) as num 
    FROM users LEFT JOIN comments ON comments_id = id 
    WHERE user_id = 4
    GROUP BY cid";
$dbc = mysqli_query($sql);
if (!$dbc) trigger_error(mysqli_error($mysqli).$sql);
```

(Note that I have assigned a query to a variable first. That's great for the debugging purposes. Always do it this way)

Though I don't understand the meaning of the first loop at all. Doesn't your first query return only one row? Why to loop then? just fetch a row and then use in the output.

And your main problem, as Jan noted in comments, is you reopen a database connection. While it must be opened only once. You don't have to connect to the database every time you run a query. Do it only once.
What is the book you're learning from?

Comment: The correct syntax to call the array should be: {$row['id']}.

Comment: That is much better code than OP's. The query string should always be in a variable it makes debugging much easier.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking the wrong question here.
Yes you could use $row['id'] in the nested query. You can concatenate it to the query string using the '.' operator.

```
$dbc2 = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT COUNT(cid) as num
                                      FROM comments
                                      WHERE comments_id = ".$row['id']);
```

However that is horible. You should also use only one connection and store the variables in a central place.

You should change you query to something like this (not tested):

```
SELECT 
  users.*, 
  (SELECT count(*) 
  FROM comments 
  WHERE comments.user_id = users.user_id) AS 'comment_count'
FROM users
LEFT JOIN comments ON 
  comments.user_id = user.user_id
WHERE users.user_id = 4;
```

By adding a select statement as the count field you are getting everything you want in a single query.
That should avoid all those ugly loops. If you are doing these queries inside loops it will be very slow and there is usually a way to do the same thing in one more complex query.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the syntax you've presented, but you make a good point - looking at his sql, he should be able to do it with just one query - though I'm a still a bit confused about the column names.

Comment: Hmm... I'm just used to very explicitly stated joins, "SELECT a.apple, b.blah FROM TableA a LEFT JOIN TableB b ON TableA.id=b.apple_id"

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel Yeah, I forgot that join. It's in their now.

Joining counts is okay if you only have one result. However it won't work if you need a list of all users and their comment count, or all customers and their total spend. When trying to bring in aggregated data I found this page quite useful:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/598355/mysql-statement-combining-a-join-and-a-count

It's called a correlated subquery. 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/correlated-subqueries.html

If there is a quicker way to do this I would like to know. Mysql is meant to suck at nested queries.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I avoid using generic variable names like $row and $result for this very reason - you are going to come unstuck when you are doing complicated loops like this, and it is generally good practice to have variables with descriptive names like $user or $comment.

Also - @Keyo's point about using a subquery will help significantly reduce the number of queries you have to make to the database.

Comment: This is the reason why I write models and use a database class instead of writing queries inline :)

Comment: generic names are handy. better improve your app's design to avoid such cases.

Comment: and with a subquery number of queries run by the database will be the same/

Comment: @Shrapnel - but the number of query calls to the database will be reduced... saving some overhead

Comment: You have no idea of overhead.

Comment: Actually, yes I do - or at least more of an idea than you have charm - I readily admit that a single join is more efficient than a sub-select, but that doesn't stop a sub-select with a single call from PHP being more efficient than multiple calls to the database. Or would you like to be a bit more patronising?

Answer (score -1):

I don't know what's the structure of your tables, so I will assume that **id** is actually **user_id** since I believe you are trying to associate the user with its comments. Maybe you made a mistake rewriting the code to post it here? Anyway, my last point will be based on these assumptions.

1. There is no need to reconnect to the same database inside the loop.
2. Your second loop shouldn't overwrite the $row array. Use $row2 instead to prevent headaches.
3. You can do all the work in a single query as stated above with LEFT JOIN or subqueries.
4. Your first query returns a single record, so, there is no need to loop through it.
5. Here is your fully rewritten code, not tested and assuming that you want to display the user data based on my assumptions in the first paragraph.

   $mysqli = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "sitename");
   $dbc = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT users.*,
                                COUNT(cid) AS num 
                                FROM users LEFT JOIN comments ON comments_id = user_id
                                WHERE user_id = 4
                                GROUP BY users.user_id");

   if (!$dbc) {
       // There was an error...do something about it here...
       print mysqli_error($mysqli);
   }

   if($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($dbc)){
    echo 'User: ' . $row['user_id'] . '';
    echo 'Link To User' . $row['user_id'] . '';
    echo 'User ' . $row['user_id'] . ' Comments# ' . $num . '';
   }

Next time please provide your table structures so we can give a more accurate solution to your problem.

### Quick Reference: Using Quotes

I will explain something here since I saw some of you make the same mistake with quotes a couple of times in your responses to this post.

This is what you tell PHP when you use quotes:

**Single Quotes:** Do not parse here.
**Double Quotes:** Parse the contents inside the quotes, please.
**No Quotes:** This is a constant or number, please parse if it's a constant only.

When you're working with arrays, the element inside the square brackets should be single quoted if there is nothing to be parsed there. If there is a number or a constant, you can drop the quotes. For instance:

```
// If your string is double quoted, you use regular brackets to encapsulate the array
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tableA WHERE id = {$myarray['id']}";
```

Or, there is another similar approach:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tableA WHERE id = ".$myarray['id'];
```

Which can also be written like:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM tableA WHERE id = '.$myarray['id'];
```

Another couple of examples:

```
// This is correct
echo $myarray[5];

// If you are using constants, this is correct too
define('MYCONSTANT', 5);  
echo $myarray[MYCONSTANT];

// This shouldn't be used, because 'name' isn't a constant...
echo $myarray[name];

// Use this instead...
echo $myarray['name'];

// Or, like I explained above, escape the array
echo "My name is {$myarray['name']}";
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Can someone edit my post and format the code below point 5? Markdown won this time.

Comment: What all this quick and HUGE reference for?