# complex(?) mysql correlated counting query. please help?

Tags: mysql

Suppose the following situation.
Persons assigned to tasks, and I want to return Person id, Person Name, the number of tasks completed by each person from the following tables.

Table Name - Field Name

Person - id, Name

Task_Person_Combi - Task_id, Person_id

Task* - returns id of Task (actually this is LEFT Joined table which returns id of persons)
(Task has over 100,000 rows, and the query has to be quick well less than 1 second)

After reading [MySQL statement combining a join and a count?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/598355/mysql-statement-combining-a-join-and-a-count), I'm trying the following. (but this doesn't seem to work, and I'm kind of lost)

```
SELECT id, Name,
(
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM Task_Person_Combi C
    WHERE P.id=C.Person_id AND C.Task IN (SELECT id FROM Task* - this is Joined table)
) AS Count
FROM Person P
WHERE id>0
HAVING Count>0
ORDER BY Name
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Try this?

```
SELECT id, Name,
      COUNT(T.ID)  AS TaskCount

FROM Person AS P
INNER JOIN Task_Person_Combi AS C ON  P.id=C.Person_id 
LEFT JOIN TASK AS T ON C.Task = T.id
WHERE id>0
AND T.id IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY id,Name
HAVING COUNT(T.ID)>0
ORDER BY Name
```

Comment: thanks. This would work for counting all tasks. but I also need to refine tasks by other conditions using something like "WHERE C.Task IN (another subquery from different multiple tables)" like 'count tasks within last month or within this region etc'. (btw, this subquery uses LEFT JOIN and GROUP BY). I'm still working on it 'cos when I add this condition to your code, it takes over 300 secs. I can't use LIMIT in subquery, so I'm quite lost again.