# Advanced Mysql Query to get master record if two conditions matches on different rows of child records

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I was writing a mysql filter query which has a primary table and another table which holds multiple records against each record of primary table (I will call this table child).

Am trying to write a query which fetches record of primary table based on its values on child table. If the child table condition is one then I will be able to do it simply by joining, but I have 2 conditions which falls on same field.

```
For ex.
table 1:
id   name  url
1    XXX   http://www.yahoo.com
2    YYY   http://www.google.com
3    ZZZ   http://www.bing.com

table 2:
id masterid optionvalue
1  1        2
2  1        7
3  2        7
4  2        2
5  3        2
6  3        6
```

My query has to return unique master records when the `optionvalue` matches only both 2 different conditions match on second table.
I wrote query with IN...

```
select * from table1 
left join table2 on table1.id=table2.masterid 
where table2.optionvalue IN(2,7) group by table1.id;
```

This gets me all 3 records because IN is basically checking 'OR', but in my case I should not get 3rd master record because it has values 2,6 (there is no 7). If I write query with 'AND' then am not getting any records...

```
select * from table1 
left join table2 on table1.id=table2.masterid 
where table2.optionvalue = 2 and table2.optionvalue = 7;
```

This will not return records as the and will fail as am checking different values on same column. I wanted to write a query which fetches master records which has child records with field `optionvalues` holds both 2 and 7 on different records.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: A third table alias using child a second time

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Indeed, as AsConfused hinted, you need to two joins to TABLE2 using aliases

-- `both of these are tested`:

```
-- find t1 where it has 2 and 7 in t2

    select t1.*
    from table1 t1
    join table2 ov2 on t1.id=ov2.masterid and ov2.optionValue=2
    join table2 ov7 on t1.id=ov7.masterid and ov7.optionValue=7

-- find t1 where it has 2 and 7 in t2, and no others in t2

select t1.*, ovx.id
    from table1 t1
      join table2 ov2 on t1.id=ov2.masterid and ov2.optionValue=2
      join table2 ov7 on t1.id=ov7.masterid and ov7.optionValue=7
      LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 ovx on t1.id=ovx.masterid and ovx.optionValue not in (2,7)
    WHERE ovx.id is null
```

Comment: As @ashalynd noted this will doesn't work if OP meant "when the optionvalue matches only both 2 different conditions match on second table" that it should match these 2 values and no other.

Comment: Works fine and performs

Comment: Well, someone added a 2nd example above that handled the "not in (2,7)" by adding a third join and `group by`.  The GROUP BY is unnecessary, so I updated/replaced that example to accomplish the same without any `GROUP BY` using a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` (alias ovx).   Note: the OP never asked for this variation, but I didn't want to leave a questionable solution.

Comment: @Stan - thank you very much sir... that 'find t1 where it has 2 and 7 in t2' query worked perfect...

Comment: @Stan - if you don't mind can you also tell what type of join it is... when you does not mention 'left' or 'right' or 'inner' or 'outer' ? i mean the key word 'join' basically does what join ?

Comment: Sorry, to be clear: A `JOIN` without a modifier defaults to an `INNER JOIN`

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this (no performance guarantees, and assumes you only want exact matches):

```
select table1.* from table1 join
(select masterid, group_concat(optionvalue order by optionvalue) as opt from table2 
group by masterid) table2_group on table1.id=table2_group.masterid
where table2_group.opt='2,7';
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/673094/9

Comment: As written that would get results only if 2,7 were the only option values as opposed to if they were among the option values. If you you add a WHERE  optionvalue=2 or optionvalue=7 before the group by, I think it would work. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ba84c/2

Comment: Also, how does group_concat determine the order? I'll look it up.

Comment: OP said "My query has to return unique master records when the optionvalue matches only both 2 different conditions match on second table." I understood that as "2 and 7 must be the only values to match". If that is not the case, then you are right. Regarding the order, I added ORDER BY clause.

Comment: Fair point. I stand correct. And you added the order by on group_concat which works nicely.

Answer (score 0):

select * from t1 where id in
(select masterid from t2 where
(t2.masterid in (select masterid from t2 where optionvalue=2))
and (t2.masterid in (select masterid from t2 where optionvalue=7)))

Old school :-) Query took 0.0009 sec.

Answer (score -2):

This can also be done without the joins using correlated exists subqueries. That may be more efficient.

```
select *
  from table1 
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table2 WHERE table1.id=table2.masterid and optionvalue = 2)
   AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table2 WHERE table1.id=table2.masterid and optionvalue = 7)
```

If this is to be an exclusive match as suggested by, "when the optionvalue matches only both 2 different conditions match on second table" then you could ad yet a third exists condition. Performance-wise this may start to break down.

```
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table2 WHERE table1.id=table2.masterid AND optionvalue  NOT IN (2,7)
```

Edit: A note on correlated subqueries from [Which one is faster: correlated subqueries or join?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12376435/which-one-is-faster-correlated-subqueries-or-join).

Comment: 1. I'm sorry you are confused by the GROUP BY. Would you prefer DISTINCT? Though you are correct that I could just drop it all together. 2)  I fail to see how check for exists/no exists is more complicated than a join. 3) Really? Copy, paste, edit a character makes you fingers hurt?

Comment: Removed the extraneous GROUP BY. Thanks @AsConfused

Comment: Table aliases are irrelevant in this case--don't get hung up on the. No idea what you mean by "you should know about performance anyway." Exist/Not Exists is often more performant than JOIN, but it would be hard to gauge with actual performance in this without a meaningful dataset.