# Mysql get records having multiple values on a different (relational) table (manyToMany)

Tags: mysql, sql, doctrine

I need some help getting records based on a criteria where joining items table with their values table, having multiple search values.

Items table

```
+----+-----------+
| id |   title   |
+----+-----------+
| 82 | Test ITEM |
+----+-----------+
```

Attributes table

```
+----+--------------+
| id |  Attribute   |
+----+--------------+
|  1 | An Attribute |
+----+--------------+
```

Item Attribute Values table

```
+----+---------+--------------+-----------+
| id | item_id | attribute_id | option_id |
+----+---------+--------------+-----------+
|  1 |      82 |            1 |        25 |
|  1 |      82 |            1 |         3 |
+----+---------+--------------+-----------+
```

What i did:

```
SELECT 
p.*
FROM 
product_products p 
LEFT JOIN
product_attribute_values v ON v.product_id = p.id
LEFT JOIN
product_attribute_options o ON o.id = v.option_id
WHERE 
(p.id = 82 OR p.parent_id = 82) AND
(o.id IN (25, 3))
GROUP BY p.id
```

But there is a problem with this query because it returns all items having 3 OR 25 values.

I want to return items only that has 25 and 3 values at the same time.

Tried this: 
[Advanced Mysql Query to get master record if two conditions matches on different rows of child records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30959041/advanced-mysql-query-to-get-master-record-if-two-conditions-matches-on-different)

Same result.

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this query

```
SELECT p.id,p.title
FROM product_products p 
LEFT JOIN product_attribute_values v ON v.product_id = p.id
LEFT JOIN product_attribute_options o ON o.id = v.option_id
WHERE (p.id = 82 OR p.parent_id = 82)
  AND (o.id IN (25, 3))
GROUP BY p.id,p.title
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT o.id) = 2
```

Add `option_id`

```
SELECT p.*,o.id
FROM
  (
    SELECT p.id,p.title
    FROM product_products p 
    JOIN product_attribute_values v ON v.product_id = p.id
    JOIN product_attribute_options o ON o.id = v.option_id AND o.id IN (25, 3)
    WHERE (p.id = 82 OR p.parent_id = 82)
    GROUP BY p.id,p.title
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT o.id) = 2
  ) p
JOIN product_attribute_values v ON v.product_id = p.id
JOIN product_attribute_options o ON o.id = v.option_id AND o.id IN (25, 3)
```

Comment: It's working now. I will try this query with more than 2 values. I could not think using having  as a final condition :) Good job!