# How to do a join between two tables based on a condition?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have this query:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN A.name IS NULL THEN B.name ELSE A.name END) 
FROM mytable A LEFT JOIN mytable B ON (A.related=B.id)
```

It works, but that `JOIN` always happens, I mean that `JOIN` occurs for those two cases:

- `WHEN A.name IS NULL THEN B.name`
- `ELSE A.name`

I want to avoid that. I mean I want to do a `JOIN` only for this condition `WHEN A.name IS NULL` not all the time *(My purpose is avoiding of useless joining)*. How can I do that?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "useless joining"?

Comment: I mean if `A.name IS NULL` isn't *true*, then I don't need to that `JOIN`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this would be any more efficient, but technically using a `correlated subquery` would remove the extra `join`:

```
SELECT 
  CASE WHEN name IS NULL 
  THEN (SELECT name FROM mytable B WHERE A.related = b.id)
  ELSE A.name 
  END 
FROM mytable A
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/69a0e/2)

More information: [Which one is faster: correlated subqueries or join?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12376435/which-one-is-faster-correlated-subqueries-or-join)

Comment: A short question, that sub-query will be execute when `name IS NULL` isn't *true* ?

Comment: And also what about that `JOIN` in my query? Will it be executed when `name IS NULL` isn't *true*?

Answer (score 1):

You can't really partially avoid a join, this might; but it is probably just faster to do the original join, since it is likely all this does is add to the conditions calculated for each row comparison.

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN A.name IS NULL THEN B.name ELSE A.name END) 
FROM mytable A 
LEFT JOIN mytable B ON A.name IS NULL AND A.related=B.id
;
```

Technically, this would avoid it, but I highly doubt it would be faster.

```
SELECT A.name
FROM mytable A 
WHERE A.name IS NOT NULL
UNION
SELECT B.name
FROM mytable A 
LEFT JOIN mytable B ON A.related=B.id
WHERE A.name IS NULL
;
```

Edit: On second thought, on **very large datasets** this might be something that could be helpful; but even then, you are not likely to be selecting entire table contents in such scenarios.

Comment: Oh .. adding `A.name IS NULL` on the `ON` clause is somehow clever .. thank you. upvote.

Comment: To be honest, I don't like your second query. All I want to know, Which one would be your choose? Your first query? Your second query? My query in the question?

Comment: @stack like I said in my first sentence though, depending on how the MySQL query optimizer handles it, adding that condition may not prevent row comparisons, and instead add an extra operation to every row comparison.

Comment: @stack the original query in your question. Trying to avoid "unnecessary joining" is in most cases likely to cost more than just doing the join normally. The second query is the only way that actually might be of benefit under the circumstances I outlined in the "edit" note.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COALESCE(A.name, B.name) AS name
FROM mytable A 
LEFT JOIN mytable B ON (A.related=B.id AND A.name IS NULL)
```

Comment: Sometimes we overthink or solutions ;)