# sql select events including the very first record just before range start time

Tags: java, sql

I need to plot events in a barchart that have a start time and end time.

Table structure:
id:         the id of workstation
var_id:     event type (past, forecast)
event_time: timestamp
value:      value that comes with event (state)

What i need to have are the events with event_time between chartStartTime and chartEndTime AND the very first event just before chartStartTime, dosn't matter when this event_time was.

How to combine this criterias in one SELECT?
Not to forget about performance because the table can hold millions of records!

What i tried til now is first select the event before starttime:

```
SELECT event_time, value FROM table   
WHERE id = xy AND event_time < startTime ORDER BY event_time desc LIMIT 1
```

then:

```
SELECT event_time, value FROM table
WHERE id = xy AND (var_id = past OR var_id = forecast)
AND event_time >= startTime AND event_time < endTime
ORDER BY event_time ASC
```

This queries are in a while loop that is a resultset of found workstations. xy is the id of the workstation.

This is giving me hard time because I'm not so much expirienced in sql.
I'd appreciate your help

TABLE DEFINITION:

```
CREATE TABLE a_value( 
id          INTEGER     DEFAULT '0',
var_id      INTEGER     DEFAULT '0',
event_time  INTEGER     DEFAULT '0',
value       FLOAT       DEFAULT '0',
PrimKeya_value
PrimKey2(id,var_id,event_time)
)
INDEX-DEFINITION:
CREATE INDEX aValueTimeFirst ON a_value (event_time)
```

My actual query:

```
select event_time, value_f from a_value use index (aValueTimeFirst)
where id = 5866 and var_id in (-350, -351)
and event_time >= (
  select event_time from a_value where id = 5866 and event_time < 1484552880
  order by event_time desc limit 1
) order by event_time asc
```

Execution plan: for test table with 11 million records:
[image: Execution plan: for test table with 11 million records]

Answer (score 0):

You can use union to combine these 2 query results:

```
(SELECT event_time, value FROM table   
WHERE id = xy AND event_time < startTime ORDER BY event_time desc LIMIT 1)
union
(SELECT event_time, value FROM table
WHERE id = xy AND (var_id = past OR var_id = forecast)
AND event_time >= startTime AND event_time < endTime
ORDER BY event_time ASC)
```

also you can get result using this:

```
(SELECT event_time, value FROM table
WHERE id = xy AND (var_id = past OR var_id = forecast)
AND event_time >= (SELECT event_time FROM table   
WHERE id = xy AND event_time < startTime ORDER BY event_time desc LIMIT 1)
AND event_time < endTime
ORDER BY event_time ASC)
```

check more on union here [union](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp)

Comment: What about the performance with UNION, as i did read somewhere it scans the table twice (once for each select)? I will try both of your suggestions and see how it works anyway..

Comment: union have performance issue. check on second solution with correlated query. it gives better performance check here [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12376435/which-one-is-faster-correlated-subqueries-or-join] (corrolated performance)

Comment: Well it is usefull for me but i do have a performance issue. It takes about 8 minutes to query the table because of billions of records, and that is not acceptable! So I need a better and faster way to get the result, any ideas?

Comment: create index on event_time column and use it for select operation. to create index check here [https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-indexes.htm](index creation). and using index for select check here [http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/index-hints.html](select using index) .

Comment: there is already an index on event_time.. see question edit for table and index definition and execution plan

Comment: Can you check with this and let me know the query cost:                                  select event_time, value_f from a_value use index (aValueTimeFirst)
where id = 5866 and var_id in (-350, -351)
and event_time >= (
  select max(event_time) from a_value where id = 5866 and event_time < 1484552880
) order by event_time asc;

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133527/discussion-between-devram-kandhare-and-inuendo).